# Empty row with Excel insert

Tags: c#

With these loops it sends the information to Excel. With an entire group of information it may have a total of 6 to maybe 35 rows. Each time it inserts an empty row between the second and third row of information. Any clue as to why ?. I thought with the " -- i " it would delete any empty row at the end that it may try to insert.

```
 for (BndlRow = 0; BndlRow < bundleRows; BndlRow++)
        {
            if (((System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtQtyBundle" + BndlRow]).Text != "0" &&
                ((ComboBox)srcBundlePanel.Controls["cboPaystructureBundle" + BndlRow]).Text.ToString() == "Nonrecurring")
            {
                // worksheet.Rows[currentRow + BndlRow].Insert();
                worksheet.Rows[currentRow + newRow].Insert();
                worksheet.Rows[currentRow + newRow].Font.Size = 14;
                worksheet.Rows[currentRow + newRow].Font.Bold = false;
                worksheet.Cells[currentRow + newRow, "E"].Font.Bold = true;
                worksheet.Rows[currentRow + newRow].Interior.Color = CyberaWhite;
                worksheet.Columns["A"].Interior.Color = CyberaGrey;
                worksheet.Columns["J:XFD"].Interior.Color = CyberaGrey;
                worksheet.Cells[currentRow + newRow, "C"].Interior.Color = CyberaPurple;
                worksheet.Rows[currentRow + newRow].HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                worksheet.Cells[currentRow + newRow, "D"].HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                worksheet.Cells[currentRow + newRow, "D"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtQtyBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
                worksheet.Cells[currentRow + newRow, "E"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtProductNameBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
                worksheet.Cells[currentRow + newRow, "F"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtListPriceBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
                worksheet.Cells[currentRow + newRow, "G"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtMaxDiscountBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
                worksheet.Cells[currentRow + newRow, "H"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtProposedPriceBundle" + BndlRow].Text.Replace("I", "Included").Replace("EV", "Evaluation").Replace("EX", "Existing"); //REPLACES**                                                                                                                               // Increment the counter so we track how many lines we actually added.
                newRow++;
                string DescriptionSplit = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtProductDescBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
                string[] descriptionParts = DescriptionSplit.Split('|');
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < descriptionParts.Length; i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Rows[currentRow + newRow + i].Insert();    //applies the description for the default bundle row
                    worksheet.Rows[currentRow + newRow + i].Font.Bold = false;
                    worksheet.Cells[currentRow + newRow + i, "E"].Value = rowIndent + descriptionParts[i].Trim();
                }
                currentRow += newRow + --i;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could use foreach() on bundleRows.

Comment: are you saying replace the for with foreach?, no success

Comment: Yes, in simplest terms.  You could use LINQ as well to loop through the objects, but foreach() {} will ensure you are only working with those objects and not going beyond the bounds. foreach() is a tad slower due to loading each object, however it should not be noticeable with the above example.